# Zend ldap function getAttribute() string processing

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi I am using the zend ldap function getAttribute to, obviously, get an attributes value. The particular value is, in Openldap: "telephoneNumber", "+0123456789"

When I echo this value from my Zend application It seems to strip of + and 0, and I'm not sure how it's doing it or how to stop it.

Code:

```
echo "Element: " . $this->_getNode()->getAttribute("telephoneNumber", 0) . "\n";
```

Result:

```
Element: 123456789
```

the _getNode() function just returns a node for a particular user

Any ideas on how to stop this?

More info:

```
var_dump($this->_getNode()->getAttribute("telephoneNumber", 0));
float(123456789)
```

Comment: Can you try `var_dump($this->_getNode()->getAttribute("telephoneNumber", 0))`? It seems that the attribute isn't treated as a string...

Comment: Results in the main post, seems it is a float, not sure why though!

Comment: Ok seems its fixed in http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11639, I should probably update

Comment: Well, you just need to upgrade to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by upgrading to latest Zend library, not sure if this question is of much use to the community?